# Доступ к web серверу запущенному на Windows 10 из интернета

Tags: сервер, windows-10, tp-link

Раньше, на win 7, разворачивал web сервер, на роутере указывал в DMZ статический ip машины и все работало. Сейчас, нечего не получается. Брандмауэр отключил, антивирус (штатный) отключил, UAC отключил, но все равно, что -то не пускает. Попробовал поставить ddns утилиту, тоже без результатов. Роутер Tp-Link у него тоже есть возможность указать учётку ddns, и домен, но это тоже не прокатило.

Comment: Больше конкретики. Пинг, трассировка, настройки всех имеющихся фаерволов, проброс портов

Comment: Ну и информацию об интернет-провайдере и условиях предоставления им внешнего IP-адреса

Comment: Статического внешнего ip нет. Если я не ошибаюсь, noip.com ddns  должны решать эту проблему. Проброс портов, внешний 8189 на мой ip в локалке на этот же порт, и 80 на 80, 443 на 443. Провайдер etype.ru

Comment: noip.com и ddns решают проблему отсутствия статического IP, но не проблему внешнего IP. Если у вас IP не внешний, то подключиться извне в принципе невозможно

Comment: Спасибо. Ушел разворачивать VPS

Comment: Первые 2 цифры ип адреса какие?

Comment: А ещё попробуйте указать порт больше 10000. На роутере проброс с 80 на 10080 например.

Comment: 195.135.*.* с портами завтра уже попробую

Comment: @andreymal, тогда как у него на win7 работало?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю, автор же не рассказал) Из банального — интернет-оператор, возможно, другой был

Comment: Во времена win 7 я жил в другом месте, с другим оператором и был статический внешний ip.

Comment: Я просто думал, что проблему динамического ip решает ddns на роутере, но оказалось, что нет. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию виндовс блокирует входящие соединения из неродных сетей. Надо "открыть" порт в виндовс.

В брэндмауэре добавить правило разрешающее, потом открыть его свойства и поставить в области "удаленный адрес" любой ip. В дополнительно поставить разрешить прохождение NAT. И ещё что-то... Пока не вспомнил. Найду - обновлю ответ.

Comment: Брандмауэр и антивирус отключены, так что нет

Comment: При отключенном фаерволе тоже блочит. Если явно не открыть в политике

Comment: Завтра скриншотну где именно, там далеко копаться... Заодно и принтер с шары в впн открою(давно просили)

Comment: Не блочит, я лично проверял

Comment: @andreymal у меня на фирме 6 компов с виндой, 4 блочат, 2 не блочат.. 2 из тех 4х вылечил, один не нужен других сетях, ещё одна семёрка осталась. Переехала в другую сеть недавно, надо старые ресурсы раздать. От чего зависит особо не ясно)

Comment: Ок, не исключаю такой вариант, я имел дело с одной-единственной вин10)

Comment: @andreymal только сейчас попробовал проброс  сделать со старого ноута. Ни в какую не хочет) и с фаерволом и без него. На роутере вижу внешнее подключение, но хттп клиент сваливается в таймаут.

Comment: попробовал сейчас на второй вин10 — отключения брандмауэра у меня всё равно достаточно (антивирус не стоит, разрешающие правила для Python предварительно удалил) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhMN5Boj7Hs